# Erro não reconhecido

Tags: python, matemática

Eu tenho que fazer uma função onde apresente o resultado da média e do desvio padrão:

```py
def challenge2(*args):
    """return average and standard deviation"""
    t=0
    for i in lista:
        t=i**2
        avg=sum(lista)/len(lista)
        std=(t/len(lista)-avg**2)**(1/2)
    print("The avarege is:",avg)
    print("The standard deviation is:",std)

lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

challenge2(lista)
```

No entanto, a saída está errada para o desvio padrão:

```
The avarege is: 3.5
The standard deviation is: (1.5308084989341916e-16+2.5j)
```

Alguém sabe identificar onde está o erro?

Answer (score 0):

Levando em consideração que para calcular o desvio-padrão é necessário realizar um somatório, você deve, no laço *for* que percorre a lista, adicionar à variável *t* o valor que deve ser acrescentado ao somatório e, após o laço, dividir esse valor pelo tamanho da lista menos 1 (ou apenas pelo tamanho da lista, caso seja uma população - nesse caso considerei que a lista representa uma amostra. Se for uma população, retire o " -1" da divisão). O código completo fica assim (usei a função *sqrt* da biblioteca *math* para realizar o cálculo da raíz quadrada):

```
import math

def challenge2(*args):
    """return average and standard deviation"""
    t=0
    avg = sum(lista)/len(lista)
    
    for i in lista:
        t = t + (i - avg) ** 2
        
    std = math.sqrt((t / (len(lista) - 1)))
        
    print("The avarege is:", avg)
    print("The standard deviation is:", std)

lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

challenge2(lista)
```

Algo importante: no seu código, o cálculo da média estava sendo realizado dentro do laço que percorre a lista, o que é desnecessário, pois é possível calculá-la uma única vez antes do *for*.

[Veja funcionando no repl.it](https://repl.it/@Jvsierra_/FussyDesertedOpentracker#main.py)

Comment: Muito obrigada! Ajudou muito

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você deseja implementar uma função que retorne tanto a [Média Aritmética](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/matematica/media-aritmetica.htm) quanto o [Desvio Padrão](https://www.educamaisbrasil.com.br/enem/matematica/desvio-padrao) dos valores. Para resolver esta questão você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo:

```
from math import pow, sqrt


def media_desvio_padrao(lis):
    soma = sum(lis)
    quant = len(lis)
    avg = (soma / quant)

    soma_t = 0
    for item in lis:
        soma_t += pow((item - avg), 2)
    std = sqrt(soma_t / quant)
    return avg, std


valores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

media, desvio_padrao = media_desvio_padrao(valores)

print(f'\033[32mA Média Aritmética é: {media:.2f}')
print(f'O Desvio Padrão é: {desvio_padrao:.2f}')
```

Observe que neste algoritmo foi implementada uma função que recebe como parâmetro uma lista e retorna dois valores que são: **média e desvio padrão**.

Quando executamos este código, recebemos as seguintes saídas

```
A Média Aritmética é: 3.50
O Desvio Padrão é: 1.71
```

**Detalhes**

Quando executamos o código a lista é passada como argumente para a função `media_desvio_padrao`. Nesta função é calculado a soma dos valores da lista (soma), a quantidade de valores da lista (quant) e a média aritmética desses valores (avg).

Em seguida, a lista `valores` e percorrida pelo laço de repetição `for` e, a cada interação do fór, é incrementada a variável `soma_t`, a qual é responsável pelo acúmulo da operação `pow((item - avg), 2)`. Em seguida, é calculado o `desvio padrão`.

Posteriormente a função `media_desvio_padrao` retorna **dois valores**, que são: `avg` (média aritmética) e `std` (desvio padrão).

Logo em seguida, é exibido os resultados **formatados** com duas casas decimais.

Agora, imagine que você deseja trabalhar com uma quantidade indefinida de listas e valores. Neste caso, você precisará de um algoritmo que seja capaz de trabalhar com várias listas. Para esta situação podemos utilizar o seguinte algoritmo:

```
from math import pow, sqrt


def media_desvio_padrao(lis):
    soma = sum(lis)
    quant = len(lis)
    avg = (soma / quant)

    soma_t = 0
    for item in lis:
        soma_t += pow((item - avg), 2)
    std = sqrt(soma_t / quant)
    return avg, std


valores = list(map(int, input('Digite os valores: ').split()))

media, desvio_padrao = media_desvio_padrao(valores)

print(f'\033[32mA Média Aritmética é: {media:.2f}')
print(f'O Desvio Padrão é: {desvio_padrao:.2f}')
```

Quando executamos este segundo algoritmo recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite os valores:` . Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os valores da lista, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `Enter`.

A partir deste momento serão realizados todas as operações descritas anteriormente.

**Observação 1**

Com este código podemos calcular a `Média Aritmética` e o `Desvio Padrão` de quaisquer listas contendo valores `inteiros`.

**Observação 2**

Com este código, podemos inserir por lista, quantos valores quisermos.

**Observação 3**

Para encerrar a inserção de valores na lista, basta pressionar a tecla `enter`.

Comment: Show! Consegui fazer aqui, obrigada!

Comment: Se a resposta funcionou corretamente seria de bom tom marca-la, clicando no `V` ao lado da resposta. Pois, marcando desta forma, a resposta fica em evidência para novos usuários.